# Подключение AForge к проекту - C++/CLI WinForms

Tags: aforge

Добрый день. Занялся подключением AForge к проекту WinForms. Скопировал файл AForge.Video.FFMPEG.dll в папку Debug проекта. В ссылках добавил файл через браузер. В заголовке прописал using "AForge.Video.dll" и using "AForge.Video.DirectShow.dll"
Прописал using namespace AForge::Video; и using namespace AForge::Video.DirectShow; Компилирую .......

Результат - fatal error C1107: не удается найти сборку "AForge.Video.FFMPEG.dll": укажите путь поиска сборок с помощью переключателя /AI или переменной среды LIBPATH

Что я сделал неправильно или что еще не сделал ?

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос закрыт. Надо было еще добавить директорию dll-файла в Проект-Страницы св-в->C++->Общие->Разрешать ссылки #using